# Hide the address bar after opening a link in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to hide the address bar of the browser which gets redirected when I click on a link in react-native app using Linking. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hide address bar of the browser. Instead, you may try to use [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#docsNav) inside your app and display your website.

```
<WebView
   source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
   style={{marginTop: 20}} />
```

Comment: can you hide a top bar of the WebView?

Comment: I am not sure which top bar are you talking about. WebView is just like any other view, you may style it the way you want.

Comment: React native's WebView has been deprecated now and will be removed from core modules. You must use this library instead https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with React and Capacitor, but new to React Native